# Data from User Sources option disappear in Stimulsoft designer

Tags: stimulsoft

I have used Stimulsoft 2023.1 from last year and I have did all my reports on it with "Data from User Sources " options. today I've opened the designer and wanted to choose a new "data from user source in object section" in it but this options doesn't exist.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF71D.png)
I am looking every site and all Stimulsoft forum but didn't find any thing.

I have reset the designer from options menu but it didn't work.